# Find Multi-Column Primary key

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-profiling

I have about 30 tables from an old ERP which have multi-column primary keys.  Unfortunately I don't know what those keys are.  I've used the SSIS profiling task to determine primary key candidates for up to 5 columns, but it runs so slow as to be impractical.  Is there any tool that would do this faster?  My alternative is about 2 weeks of investigation using Excel and lots of select distinct queries.

Comment: Some reason you can't do it with SSMS?

Comment: Do you mean that the tables have no primary or unique constraints defined and that the application code manages the "key" values?

Comment: Yes, I mean that there are no constraints applied to them and the applications manage the key values.

Comment: You could run a trace and then use the ERP to access specific items and correlate your actions with the captured statements - but there is no guarantee that the ERP implements direct sql statements in the appropriate fashion. I don't know of any automated alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was able to get primary keys for many tables by reverse-engineering with ER/Studio using an ODBC driver.

I have no idea how they manage to get the primary keys (the reports produced by the database don't show them), but for most table it seems like they're there.

Answer (score 3):

The following should get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
        SELECT 
            i.object_id,
            index_name = i.name,
            key_column_name = c.name,
            ic.key_ordinal,
            key_col_cnt = MAX(ic.key_ordinal) OVER (PARTITION BY ic.object_id)
        FROM
            sys.indexes i
            JOIN sys.index_columns ic
                ON i.object_id = ic.object_id
                AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
            JOIN sys.columns c
                ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
                AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE 
            i.is_primary_key = 1
        ) ix
WHERE 
    ix.key_col_cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks!  The tables don't have any indexes or keys applied to them.  I'm trying to find the natural key so I can create an index and primary key.

Comment: In that case, you don't have primary keys either... or foreign keys for that matter. You just have a big mess on your hands. Just because you're able to programmatically find a set of columns that happen to be unique, doesn't mean they are suitable candidate keys. Determining a table’s primary key requires some actual human thought.